# Trigger [compareWith] programmatically in mat-select/mat-option

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I'm having employees that belong to one or more teams.
I want to be able to pick multiple employees in my dropdown OR open a dialog where I pick one or multiple teams. When I choose some teams and click ok, I search for the employees that belong to the team and add them to the formGroup-element "chosenEmployees". The value of chosenEmployees changes correctly, but the checked values in the dropdown-box is not being updated.
When I choose an employee first and then open the Teams-Dialog, it's updating the checked values in the dropdown-box.

```
<form [formGroup]="formGroup" *ngIf="this.formGroup"> 
 <div>
  <mat-form-field>
    <mat-label>{{ 'numbers' | translate }}</mat-label>
    <mat-select formControlName="chosenEmployees" [compareWith]="compareChosenEmployees" (selectionChange)="updateEmployees(chosenEmployees)" multiple disableOptionCentering>
      <mat-option *ngFor="let employee of allEmployees" [value]="employee">
        {{ employee.employeeId + '(' + employee.teamId + ')'}}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
  </mat-form-field>
  <span fxFlex="5"></span>
  <button mat-button type="submit" color="primary" (click)="addTeam()">
    <mat-icon>add</mat-icon>
    <mat-label>{{ 'teams.add' | translate }}</mat-label>
  </button>
 </div>
</form>
```

In the .ts it looks like this:
The chosenEmployee-variable:

```
public chosenEmployees: Employee[] = [];
```

My FormGroup in the ngOnInit Function:

```
 const formFields = {
  endDate: new FormControl(undefined),
  hasEnddate: new FormControl(true),
  chosenEmployees: [this.chosenEmployees]
};

this.formGroup = this.formBuilder.group(formFields);
```

My addTeam function:

```
addTeam(){
const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(AddTeamDialogComponent, {
  data:
  [
    this.chosenTeams,
    this.allTeams
  ]
});

dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe((addTeamResult: AddTeamResult) => {
  this.changeDetectorRef.markForCheck();
  if (addTeamResult){
    this.chosenTeams = addTeamResult.teams;
    if (addTeamResult.teams !== undefined){
      addTeamResult.teams.forEach(team => {
        const employees =
          this.allEmployees.filter(emp => emp.teamId === team.id);
        employees.forEach(e => {
          if (this.chosenEmployees.length === 0){
            this.chosenEmployees.push(e);
          }
          else if (!(this.chosenEmployees.find(_ => _.employeeId === e.employeeId && _.teamId === team.id))){
            this.chosenEmployees.push(e);
          }
        });
      });
    }
    this.formGroup.controls.chosenEmployees.setValue(this.chosenEmployees);
    // this.formGroup.controls["chosenEmployees"].patchValue(this.chosenEmployees);
    // this.formGroup.patchValue({chosenEmployees: this.chosenEmployees});
    this.updateEmployees(this.chosenEmployees);
    this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
  }
});}}
```

Things I tried

- using ngModel and value in the html.
- not using the formGroup but a formControl and use "formControl" in the html.
- formGroup.controls.chosenEmployees.setValue
- formGroup.controls.chosenEmployees.patchValue
- formGroup.markasdirty, formGroup.pristine, formGroup.touched
- I tried to update the used angular version
- not using [this.chosenEmployees] but new FormControl(this.chosenEmployees)

Comment: Can you provide the app in any simulator like https://stackblitz.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the problem is that the value of this.chosenEmployees is null at first, you can try, before start the process use

```
this.chosenEmployees=this.chosenEmployees || []
```

To be sure that start with an array.

BTW you can use the [spread operator](https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/future-javascript/spread-operator) to concat two arrays

```
//really I don't know what is your chosenEmployees
//I imagine that should be
//this.chosenEmployees=this.form.value.chosenEmployes || []
//but I don't know

this.chosenEmployees=this.chosenEmployees || []

addTeamResult.teams.forEach(team => {
    this.chosenEmployees=[...this.chosenEmployees,
          ...this.allEmployees.filter(emp => emp.teamId === team.id)]
})
```

Comment: For some reason, I don't need the frist part as chosenEmployees is not null in the beginning. But using the spread operator instead of push did the trick for me. Thank you so much! Do you know why this could be?

Comment: @BirnBaumBlüte, take account that the spread operator **not** avoid repeated elements. NOTE: Tthe only I see in your code that can be erroneous is if chosenEmployees is null -this is the reason I say you use the `this.chosenEmployees=this.chosenEmployees || []`, but you should see an error in "console" (when use F12 in the navigator)